# Why doesn't NVDA read the GUI in Eclipse or NetBeans, and can I get it to do that?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, netbeans, nvda

How do I use the NVDA screen reader in `windowApplication` Java in Eclipse or Java NetBeans?

I installed NVDA and tried to make it read the GUI, but it does not read anything inside i.e. dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

NVDA does not read some GUIs. Specifically, I know that it does not read tkinter and Java GUIs. As far as GUIs go for screen readers, your best bet is HTMLM/web apps. Oh, and I think .NET GUIs.